# Timestamp comparison issue in Hive when using unix_timestamp

Tags: sql, hive

I am doing some selection in hive which includes a comparison of timestamp. Please see the code.

I am using unix_timestamp to transfer a human date into a timestamp and compare with existing timestamp column, but the result is wrong.

```
select distinct starttime
from net_oss_odm.sub_location_operator_temp
where starttime < unix_timestamp('2019/08/28 14:00:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') order by starttime desc
limit 10;
```

The result:

```
1566990000
1566986400
1566982800
1566968400
1566964800
Time taken: 47.873 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

But this is not right because unix_timestamp('2019/08/28 14:00:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss') returns 1566972000.

```
hive> select unix_timestamp('2019/08/28 14:00:00','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss');
OK
1566972000
```

I tried to use 1566972000 to compare and the result is right:

```
hive> select distinct starttime from net_oss_odm.sub_location_operator_temp where starttime<1566972000 order by starttime desc limit 10;

OK
1566968400
1566964800
```

Why is this happening? How to avoid the wrong data?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon, it is a timezone issue, I finally solved the issue using the following SQL:

```
select distinct starttime from net_oss_odm.sub_location_operator_temp where starttime<unix_timestamp('2019/08/28 14:00:00+0800','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssZ') order by starttime desc limit 10;
```

When I add timezone in the DateTime format, the result looks proper.

```
unix_timestamp('2019/08/28 14:00:00+0800','yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ssZ')
```